# Get the id of an anchor when call fancybox from class attribute

Tags: jquery, class, attributes, fancybox

I'm trying to get the id from an anchor when calling a fancybox from class attribute, is there any way to do this or is neccesary to get it from the click event? I already tryed with $(this) but not working and using $(".nameOfTheClass").attr("id") neither

Here's my code:

```
$(".cerrar_actividad").fancybox({
    'scrolling'     : 'no',
    'titleShow'     : false,
    'helpers'       : {
        title  : null
    },
'beforeLoad'    : function() {
    var str  =  $(".cerrar_actividad").attr("id").split("_");
    var id_actividad = str[1];
    alert(id_actividad);
},
...
});
```

and the html code:

```
<a href="#cerrarActividad" class="cerrar_actividad" id="actividad_<?php echo $a['id_actividad'] ?>"><img src="..." /></a>
```

I need this because I need to fill one form getting the id information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `.each()`, just get the element's ID within the `afterLoad` (`beforeLoad` would work too) callback like

```
$(".cerrar_actividad").fancybox({
    afterLoad: function () {
        alert($(this.element).attr("id"))
    }
});
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/he9d2/)</kbd>

... or use `alert($(this.element).attr("id").split("_")[1])` as in your example

Comment: Great, I didn't know that I can use $(this.element) inside fancybox, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate the elements:

```
$(".cerrar_actividad").each(function () {
    var id_actividad = this.id.split("_")[1];            
    $(this).fancybox({
        'scrolling': 'no',
        'titleShow': false,
        'helpers': {
            title: null
        },
        'beforeLoad': function () {
            alert(id_actividad);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeap, that was useful, but the var id_actividad must be global, otherwise I get error saying that is not defined, thanks!

Comment: Hm, `id_actividad` should be in scope to the `beforeLoad` callback.

Comment: @JasonP : don't see why but it also works with `beforeLoad` though http://jsfiddle.net/9vqG2/1/

Comment: @JFK good call, I didn't know that fancybox gave you access to the current element.

Comment: @JasonP : you can always use `$(this.element)` to refer to `$(this)` inside fancybox's callbacks